# PDO unbuffered query still waits until query result is complete

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an SQL query which can return quite a lot results (something like 10k rows) but I cannot use the SQL LIMIT parameter, as I don't know the exact amount of needed rows (there's a special grouping done in PHP). So the plan was to stop fetching rows once I have enough.

Since PDO normally operates in buffered mode, which fetches the whole result set and passes it to PHP, I switched PDO to unbuffered mode with

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

Now I expected that executing the query should take about the same time no matter what LIMIT I pass. So basically

```
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$count = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    ++$count;
    if ($count > 10) break;
}
```

should execute in about the same time for

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM myTable';
```

and

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 10';
```

However the first one takes 8 seconds whereas the second one executes instantly. So it seems like the unbuffered query also waits until the whole result set is fetched - which shouldn't be the case according to the documentation.

**Is there any way to get the query result instantly in PHP with PDO and stop the query once I have enough results?**

Database applications like "Sequel Pro SQL" can do this (I can hit cancel after 1 second and get the results that were already queried until that time) so it can't be a general problem with MySQL servers.

I can workaround the problem by choosing a very high LIMIT which always has enough valid results after my grouping. But since performance is an issue, I'd like to query only as many entries as really needed. Please don't suggest anything that involves grouping in MySQL, the terrible performance of that is the reason we have to change the behaviour.

Comment: Do you have `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` in your query? In that case, the engine doesn't know what the first row is until it has produced the entire data set

Comment: what part does it take 8 seconds to run? is it `$result = $pdo->query($query);` or the fetch?  or anything else?

Comment: There is no GROUP BY but there is an ORDER BY using one indexed column. The thing is, that the MySQL tool I used also returns the correct first rows if I cancel the query after one second. I also used SQL_NO_CACHE to prevent any cache influence. The query operation takes the 8 seconds, the fetch has nearly no impact.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I expected that executing the query should take about the same time no matter what LIMIT I pass. So basically

This might not be completely true. While you won't get the overhead of receiving all your results, they are all queried (without a limit)! You do get the advantage of keeping most of the results serverside until you need them, but your server actually does perform the whole query first as far as I know. I'm not sure how complicated your query is, but this could be the issue?

Say for instance you have a very slow join (not indexed), but only want the first 10 by id, your query will get 10 based on the index, and then only do the join for those 10. This'll be quick

But if you don't actually limit, but ask for the result in batches, your complete join will have to be done (slow!) and then your resultsset is released in parts.

A quicker method might be to repeat your limited query untill you have your result. I know, this will increase overhead, but it might be way quicker. Only way to know is to test.

---

as response to your comment: this is from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)

> Unbuffered MySQL queries execute the query and then return a resource while the data is still waiting on the MySQL server for being fetched.

So it executes the query. The complete query. So as I tried to explain above, it will not be as quick as the same query with a `LIMIT 10`, as it doesn't perform a partial query! The fact that a different DB engine does this does not mean MySQL can...

Comment: The large amount of results in some cases is the problem, not really the query conditions. It also can't be completely true that they are all queried since I can perform the query without limits in Sequel Pro SQL, cancel the query after a second and get the first few thousand results. In PHP the query operation takes 8 seconds before I can even start fetching results. So I basically want to do the same thing as the SQL software does - just stop the query after a second (or 10 results, or any other condition).

Comment: The fact that "sequel pro sql" can do this, doesn't mean mysql can. Let me add something

Comment: "Sequel Pro SQL" is just a program to access the MySQL database directly. It's the same database, accessed with the same user. However the program has the option to stop the running query whereas PHP does not seem to have that option...

Comment: the problem i'm trying to point out is the initial query, and your statement that it shouldn't matter if you limit it or not. But it does, as the initial query will always query ALL results. And therefore it does matter. This has nothing to do with being able to cancel it by the way. So the moment you do the query, it does the complete query and that takes the same time as an unlimited query. What happens AFTER that is another matter, although i'm pretty sure you can't do anything with your PDO connection until you've fetched all your data.

Comment: You don't have to fetch all the data if you free the result manually. I totally understand your point that the LIMIT has an influence (or at least should have), however it seems that the desktop program I use can fetch the results while querying without waiting for the full query to be completed. That's basically the behaviour I want to achieve. But I see, it might not be possible with PDO...

Comment: What Workbench does, I think, is what I proposed in my answer: just query WITH a limit, and if you need more, re-query but ask for the second page. It does give some overhead, but it might be quick enough. query + fetch 0-10, then query+fetch 10-20, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using `prepare`/`execute` instead of `query`, and putting a `$stmt->closeCursor();` call after the break?

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$count = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    ++$count;
    if ($count > 10) break;
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Comment: what does prepare execute to do here?

Comment: Yes, I also tried prepared statements but they have the same problem as the normal query

Comment: Using prepared statements allow you to break query execution up into steps, and gives you more control of the execution.  `query` is the equivalent of just running a SQL statement, but using prepare/execute you control the flow of data and manage the connection at a lower level.  It's generally a good idea in most cases, as it gives you a few benefits - for example once a statement has been prepared it can be executed multiple times without have to invoke the (expensive) query parser each time.  Check the [pdostatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) doc.

Comment: The OP is executing his query just once. There is no need for a prepared statement. All your ideas are off the track